# Как можно организовать наследование моделей в Django?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно сделать несколько однотипных моделей вот такого вида

```py
class SomeRawValue(models.Model):
    # Здесь value всегда будет именно такой у всех моделей
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    approved_value = models.ForeignKey('SomeApprovedValue', 
                                        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                                        default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} -> {}'.format(self.value, self.approved_value.value)


class SomeApprovedValue(models.Model):
    # value может быть разного типа у разных моделей
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

Как лучше сделать что-то вроде миксинов в этом случае, чтобы унаследоваться от них и не писать одно и то же по сто раз?

Что-нибудь вроде такого:

```py
class SomeRawValueMixin(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    approved_value_class = None
    # Как мне здесь в approved_value использовать approved_value_class
    # чтобы передать его в ForeignKey?
    approved_value = models.ForeignKey()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} -> {}'.format(self.value, self.approved_value.value)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через abstract models:
[Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

```
class SomeApprovedValue(models.Model):
    # value может быть разного типа у разных моделей
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

# Создаешь абстрактную модель
class ApprovedValueBaseModel(models.Model):
    approved_value = models.ForeignKey(
        'SomeApprovedValue', 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Наследуешься от абстрактной модели
class SomeRawValueMixin(ApprovedValueBaseModel):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    approved_value_class = None
    # Как мне здесь в approved_value использовать approved_value_class
    # чтобы передать его в ForeignKey?
    approved_value = models.ForeignKey()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} -> {}'.format(self.value, self.approved_value.value)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```